# how to pass value to div.Attributes["style"]?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

i have a sliderdiv..i want to change the image to this div from database..the image path is saved in the database..i am retrieving the image path and passing the value of path in the below code to change the image in this div..but it's not working??
my code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection objsqlconn = new SqlConnection(con);
    objsqlconn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * From pictable", objsqlconn);

    SqlDataReader grpIDreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    grpIDreader.Read();

    string path = grpIDreader["pic1"].ToString();
    slidediv.Attributes["style"] = "background-image:url('path')";
}
```

how to pass the path to the style of slidediv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not passing actual variable `path`, the example below fixes this. Also, since you're returning a single value - no need to execute DataReader. ExecuteScalar will do:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
    SqlConnection objsqlconn = new SqlConnection(con);
    objsqlconn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 pic1 From pictable", objsqlconn);
    string path = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    slidediv.Attributes["style"] = String.Format("background-image:url('{0}')", path);
    objsqlconn.Close();
}
```